VS Code can't connect with ftp-simple
I've been battling ftp-simple for hours now and I was hoping somebody might have a solution.
I have a fresh install of VS Code
I created a folder for my projects called Projects
I have a project in that folder call it Website App
In Website App I created the .vscode folder
In the .vscode folder I created the ftp-simple.json:
{
    "remote-workspace": [
    {
        "name": "Website App",   
        "host": "giowm1136.siteground.biz",   
        "port": 21,   
        "type": "ftp",   
        "username": "ftp@mysite.com",   
        "password": "***",   
        "path": "/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra-child",   
        "autosave": true,
        "encoding": "utf8",
        "protocol": "ftp",
        "passive": true   
       }
    ]
}

Everything should be ready to go here. I have logged in with these credentials in FileZilla, so I know they work.
The problem is when I try and go to ftp-simple: FTP Config Settings I get a pop up error that says: Command 'ftp-simple: Config - FTP connection setting' resulting in an error. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
The Output window when I select ftp-simple from the dropdown says this:
[2024-09-10 13:34:25] REMOTE_WORKSPACE_PATH = c:/Users/***/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/globalStorage/humy2833.ftp-simple/remote-workspace-temp
I don't know if this is a VS Code issue or ftp-simple issue, but I'm pretty much out of ideas and I don't think ftp-simple has any support, seeing as it hasn't been updated in years.
I just want to have a connection to my wordpress files (functions.php and the ones I've created) so I can update them in real time in VS Code.

What is ftp-simple?

ftp-simple is a VS CODE extension that allows you to ftp into your server and download all of the files for a directory, so /wp-content/themes/astra-child/ for example is where your functions.php file is and if you created any folders off of that to split up your code that will be there too. It connects your code editor to your live servers files.

Opening a remote workspace looks like it has never been out of beta: https://github.com/humy2833/FTP-Simple

What is your goal? Why not just use a github repo for the files, for instance.

This issue was raised here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/227743
It is related to the new VSCode 1.93.0 update. It looks like there is no solution as of now.

I did roll back the version and had the same result. I will try again. I haven't used github before, but I think that might be the smart play.

Im having the same issue and am out of ideas on how to fix it as well

I had the same problem today, I was able to solve it by creating an empty ftp-simple.json file in the ~/.config/Code/User/ directory (this is using Linux, I guess Windows has the same style configuration folders), this generated the humy2833.ftp-simple folder with the sample files automatically inside globalStorage. I had to close and open the VSCode after creating the file for it to take effect. After that I did control+p to access the menu and accessed the option “ftp-simple: Config - FTP connection string” and the error stopped appearing when I wanted to create the configuration file.
I hope you find it useful
UPDATE: this only let open the configuration file with the VSCode without the error, but when is saved the content of the file is wiped out, i'm trying to figure out how to solve this, if i have any advance i will update again

Looks like I was able to solve it by installing an older version of VS Code (ver 1.92.2). Here is the page where it provides more details and the link to the older version of vs code github.com/humy2833/FTP-Simple/issues/322

Here’s a concise guide to modify the specified files as per your request:

Locate the file ftp-simple.json by navigating to AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\humy2833.ftp-simple\& open ftp-simple.json

Replace the existing content with the following plaintext JSON:


[{
    "name": "name",
    "host": "host",
    "port": 21,
    "type": "ftp",
    "username": "name",
    "password": "password",
    "path": "/",
    "autosave": true,
    "confirm": true
}]


Comment Out Line 980 in extension.js
by navigating to .vscode\extensions\humy2833.ftp-simple-0.7.6\ and open extension.js

Find line 980 and comment it out:
// json = cryptoUtil.decrypt(json);

Summary:
You have modified ftp-simple.json to contain plaintext credentials.
You have commented out the decryption line in extension.js to prevent it from executing.
Make sure to back up the original files before making these changes, in case you need to revert.
